# Just router username & password please

Tags: decryption, router

I want to convert my ISP hg8240t5 given router from route WAN to bridge WAN mode and they are using PPPoE connection. I also have a backup of the configuration and its file name is "hw_ctree.xml".

```
X_HW_HistoryInstance InstanceID="1" X_HW_Password="$28IfoK9A'3$!0vN-a)p8YW}nS=#w0)Ar~pR<Ff=E<{lN<2h'hFY{kl=#CrlEBTJr>~fLr/AIez7EN#CD:Hbjm3@YVH5u_R%N$mxSA$" X_HW_Time="20230503073204" X_HW_SaltVal="deb2c6c2bf37a81d6b76fb36"/>

X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" UserName="telecomadmin" Password="$2"\Av%pGcLW{@fgH4j>!C7.dFUNTFkX9,`t&onT3V_5`\:i"tlOy~.p=$`tTKOt(V:K\%(SGp\)9ncwU<ckMj@Q/Hb3w_mNCl'L8D$" UserLevel="0" Enable="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="1" Salt="2cb56abe6310524971333da9" PassMode="3" Alias="cpe-2">

<X_HW_IteratePassword Password="$2.RDBZK4a`J'iK,DZ(rGI*Cs*0^QD)B)++A1G6:x8tJ,9=ZthM4XNU27}3HLPlA$;BDU=KG`lHW~RMhWP:7vc8=Q}c+tDx++/7GCZ$" Salt="e58a3984802ed2e9abc5c4a4" IterateCount="10000" HashType="0"/>
```

I don't know which is administrator user & pass.
Would someone help me to get full access to my router.